# OfficeWriter Excel Report - bc30277 Type character '!' does not match

Tags: excel, publish, officewriter

I have an OfficeWriter report that I am trying to publish to SQL Reporting services through Excel. This is a parameterized report with just one input parameter. When I click on 'Publish' in the OfficeWriter toolbar, I get this error message:

> The value expression for the query parameter '@test' contains an error: [bc30277] Type character '!' does not match declared data type 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.....

What could be the reason for this?

Should I be deploying this from Visual Studio instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it!

It turns out officewriter or maybe ms-excel adds an '@' character in the .rdl file upon saving the report.

before:
=Parameters!@test.Value

after:
=Parameters!test.Value